# Can't install pvl8 v.2.3.15: Regenerating ninja files - FAILED: build.ninja

Tags: linux-mint, ninja, plv8

Linux Mint 20.2 , kernel 5.11.0-25-generic

I want to install plv8-2.3.15

Help here:
https://github.com/plv8/plv8/blob/v2.3.15/docs/BUILDING.md

Installed the next packages:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install git
sudo apt install python2
sudo apt install g++
sudo apt install pkg-config
sudo apt install libc-dev-bin
sudo apt install libc++abi-dev
sudo apt-get install libc++abi-dev
sudo apt install libc++-dev
sudo apt install libglib2.0-dev-bin
sudo apt install libtinfo5
sudo apt install ninja-build
```

Steps:
After `make` I get the next result:

```
./generate_upgrade.sh 2.3.15
sed -e 's/@PLV8_VERSION@/2.3.15/g' plv8.control.common | g++ -E -P -DLANG_plv8 - > plv8.control
sed -e 's/@LANG_NAME@/plv8/g' plv8.sql.common | sed -e 's/@PLV8_VERSION@/2.3.15/g' | g++ -E -P -I. -I./ -I/usr/include/postgresql/9.6/server -I/usr/include/postgresql/internal -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -D_GNU_SOURCE -I/usr/include/libxml2  -I/usr/include/mit-krb5 -DLANG_plv8 - > plv8--2.3.15.sql
sed -e 's/@PLV8_VERSION@/2.3.15/g' plv8.control.common | g++ -E -P -DLANG_plcoffee - > plcoffee.control
sed -e 's/@LANG_NAME@/plcoffee/g' plv8.sql.common | sed -e 's/@PLV8_VERSION@/2.3.15/g' | g++ -E -P -I. -I./ -I/usr/include/postgresql/9.6/server -I/usr/include/postgresql/internal -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -D_GNU_SOURCE -I/usr/include/libxml2  -I/usr/include/mit-krb5 -DLANG_plcoffee - > plcoffee--2.3.15.sql
sed -e 's/@PLV8_VERSION@/2.3.15/g' plv8.control.common | g++ -E -P -DLANG_plls - > plls.control
sed -e 's/@LANG_NAME@/plls/g' plv8.sql.common | sed -e 's/@PLV8_VERSION@/2.3.15/g' | g++ -E -P -I. -I./ -I/usr/include/postgresql/9.6/server -I/usr/include/postgresql/internal -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -D_GNU_SOURCE -I/usr/include/libxml2  -I/usr/include/mit-krb5 -DLANG_plls - > plls--2.3.15.sql
```

Nice.

Now I want to install.
Try this

```
sudo make install
```

But I get error:

```
sudo make install
cd build/v8 ; env CXXFLAGS=-fPIC CFLAGS=-fPIC ninja -C out.gn/x64.release d8
ninja: Entering directory `out.gn/x64.release'
[1/1] Regenerating ninja files
FAILED: build.ninja 
/home/Downloads/plv8-2.3.15/build/v8/buildtools/linux64/gn --root=/home/alexei/Downloads/plv8-2.3.15/build/v8 -q --check gen .
/bin/sh: 1: /home/alexei/Downloads/plv8-2.3.15/build/v8/buildtools/linux64/gn: not found
ninja: error: rebuilding 'build.ninja': subcommand failed
make: *** [Makefile:42: v8] Error 1
```